# Telegram Api: add video to existing text message in EditMessage

Tags: java, telegram

**I wonder how to add a video file to an existing text message.**

So far I have the following implemented:

1. Bot executes a SendMessage to send the first message to a user
2. The user clicks a button, which calls a callback
3. The callback is handled and the message text is changed (using EditMessageText).

But now I want to add a video file to the message when user clicks the button.

I tried this:

```
EditMessageMedia messageMedia = new EditMessageMedia();
messageMedia.setChatId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId());
messageMedia.setMedia(InputMediaVideo.builder()
        .media("src")
        .caption("test caption")
        .build()
);
```

But Telegram fairly tells me this, because the message does not contain any video yet:

```
Error editing message text: [400] Bad Request: there is no media in the message to edit
```

Is there any way to add a video to text message with EditMessage(Something) without sending a new message to a user?